# Dificuldade com repeater utilizando asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Estou com dificuldade em renderizar dinamicamente dados em um **repeater** no **asp.net webforms**.
Eu alimento o `datasource` do repeater com os registro da base de dados, e no html, preciso que seja incluida a tag `</div><div class="row">`  a cada 4 registros. Segue o html abaixo para melhor entendimento.

```
<div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="item"></div>
         <div class="item"></div>
         <div class="item"></div>
         <div class="item"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="item"></div>
         <div class="item"></div>
         <div class="item"></div>
         <div class="item"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Meu código asp.net do repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="item">....</div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

O problema é que não sei como inserir o fim, e o inicio novamente da tag `<div class="row">` a cada 4 registros no **repeater**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo assim:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 0 ? "<div class='row'>" : string.Empty %>
              <div class="item">....</div>
         <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 3 ? "</div>" : string.Empty %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Valeu @iuristona, deu certo, obrigado.